# Primefaces - Dynamic confirm dialog content

Tags: excel, jsf, primefaces

I have a JSF page that uploads a excel spreadsheet. That spreadsheet has a workbook with a certain number of rows. Before processes each row, I want to count it all and ask the user something like "Confirm the processing of X rows?"

Here is my JSF code (cancel.xhtml):

```
<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="frmMassive">
   <p:growl id="messagesUpload" showDetail="true" life="3000" />
      <h:panelGrid id="panel" columns="2">

         <h:outputText value="File" />
         <p:fileUpload value="#{cancelView.file}" mode="simple" skinSimple="true" />

         <p:spacer></p:spacer>

         <p:commandButton value="Send file" ajax="false"
            action="#{cancelView.preProcessMassive}" />
      </h:panelGrid>
   </p:panel>
</h:form>

<h:form id="frmConfirm">
   <p:commandButton style="display: none" id="confirmButton"
      actionListener="#{cancelView.postProcessMassive}">
      <p:confirm header="Confirmation"
         message="Confirm the processing of #{cancelView.lineCount} line(s)?" 
         icon="ui-icon-alert" />
   </p:commandButton>

   <p:confirmDialog global="true" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade">
      <p:commandButton value="Yes" type="button" 
         styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-yes" icon="ui-icon-check" />
      <p:commandButton value="No" type="button" 
         styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-no" icon="ui-icon-close" />
   </p:confirmDialog>
</h:form>
```

Managed Bean methods (CancelView.java):

```
public void preProcessMassive() {

   HSSFWorkbook wb;
   try {
      wb = new HSSFWorkbook(this.file.getInputstream());
   } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      return;
   }

   HttpSession session = Util.getSession();
   session.setAttribute("cancelLineCount", sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows());
   session.setAttribute("cancelSpreadSheet", file);

   RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
   context.execute("document.getElementById('frmConfirm:confirmButton').click()");
}

public int getLineCount() {
   HttpSession session = Util.getSession();
   if (session.getAttribute("cancelLineCount") == null) {
      return 0;
   } else {
      return (Integer)session.getAttribute("cancelLineCount");
   }
}
```

The problem is that my JSF page calls the method `getLineCount()` before upload the spreadsheet.

Is there another approach to count the lines of the spreadsheet and return it to the user before process it?

Comment: `Util.getSession()`? Ugh, why not just a session scoped managed bean and injecting it?

Answer (score 3):

You need to split your approach into a (at least) 2-step-wizzard.

Before you are able to determine anything about the worksheet, you (actually the user) **has** to upload it. Uploading however does not mean **processing** it, you could keep the uploaded file inside a bean property*, until the user decides to finally process it.

- Let the user choose the file
- On "Upload"-Click, upload it, analyze it
- Ask the user if he wants to process the file.

  - if yes: process it.
  - if no: drop it.

The `@ViewScoped`, `@ConversationScoped` or `@FlowScoped` Annotations might help you with this task, depending on your needs.

*For processing Excel Files some libraries can be used only with persited files and not with objects in memory. You could just store it in a temporary location as well.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, my solution is based on javascript messaging between JSF and Managed Bean.

JSF code:

```
<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="frmMassive">
   <p:growl id="messagesUpload" showDetail="true" life="3000" />
   <p:panel header="Massive Cancel" style="width: 640px;">
      <h:panelGrid id="pnlMassiveCancel" columns="2">

         <h:outputText value="File" />
         <p:fileUpload value="#{cancelView.file}" mode="simple" skinSimple="true" />

         <p:spacer></p:spacer>

         <p:commandButton value="Send" ajax="false"
            action="#{cancelView.preProcessMassive}" />
      </h:panelGrid>
   </p:panel>
</h:form>

<h:form id="frmConfirm">
   <p:remoteCommand name="postProcessMassiveCancel" 
      update="messagesConfirm" 
      actionListener="#{cancelView.postProcessMassive}" />

   <p:growl id="messagesConfirm" showDetail="true" life="3000" />
</h:form>

<h:outputScript library="js" name="cancelUtil.js" />
```

cancelUtil.js:

```
function confirmMassiveCancel(msg, postProcessFunction) {
    var result = window.confirm(msg);
    if (result == true) {
        postProcessFunction();
    }
}
```

Managed Bean code:

```
public void preProcessMassive() {
   HSSFWorkbook wb;
   try {
      wb = new HSSFWorkbook(this.file.getInputstream());
   } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      return;
   }

   HSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);

   lineCount = sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();
   HttpSession session = Util.getSession();

   RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
   String script =  "confirmMassiveCancel('Do you want to process " 
         + String.valueOf(lineCount) + " line(s)?', postProcessMassiveCancel)";
   context.execute(script);
}
```

Not an elegant solution whatsoever, but solved my problem.